# Xamarin Listview within Stacklayout displays incorrectly on iOS

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have the following xaml

```
      <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Label Text="Menu" />

        <ListView x:Name="lvMenu" ItemSelected="lvMenu_ItemSelected">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding ImageSource}" Text="{Binding TitleText}" />
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
      </StackLayout>
```

The following c# populates it

```
    private void PopulateMenu()
    {
        var menu = new List<SettingItem>()
        {
            new SettingItem() { ImageSource="icon.png", TitleText="Show All Jobs", TargetPageType = typeof(JobListPage)  },
            new SettingItem() { ImageSource="opportunities.png", TitleText="Sync Tasks", TargetPageType = typeof(SyncPage)  },
            new SettingItem() { ImageSource="leads.png", TitleText="Advanced Settings", TargetPageType = typeof(SettingsPage)  },
            new SettingItem() { ImageSource="contacts.png", TitleText="About ", TargetPageType = typeof(AboutPage)  },
        };
        lvMenu.ItemsSource = menu;
    }
```

Its all good but when it displays I get

```
 Menu
   Show All Jobs
   Sync Tasks
   Advanced Settings
```

and 7 blank lines on an iOS emulator

Comment: yes, updated question

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour on iOS for a ListView is to add the empty rows.

To overcome this, you need to wrap your ListView in a StackPanel,

Or Create a custom Rendered:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
{
     base.OnElementChanged(e);

     if (this.Control == null) return;

     this.Control.TableFooterView = new UIView();
}
```

Source : [Xamarin](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39200/how-to-hide-the-empty-rows-of-a-list-view-in-xamrin-forms-in-ios)

Comment: sorry to be dense but how would I add this code and where would I add it ?

Comment: @WelshKing Here is a step by step guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/listview/